# Array of arrays validation

Tags: laravel-5.6

I'm trying to create validation for following request - data that is passed to given endpoint needs to be an array of arrays, where each inner array contains `line1` and `postcode` and the size of the outer array is `min:1`. So, for example:

```
[
   ['line1' => 'foo', 'postcode' => 'bar'],
   ['line1' => 'baz', 'postcode' => 'qux']
]
```

is a valid data for my request and:

```
[
   ['line1' => 'foo', 'postcode' => 'bar'],
   ['line1' => 'baz']
]
```

is not.

I've created a Request validation class with following rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        '*.line1' => 'string|required',
        '*.postcode' => 'string|required',
    ];
}
```

however I don't know how to add the min requirement. Neither `'*' => 'min:1'`, nor `'' => 'min:1'` work (I'd think that first one *should* theoretically work, but I think it checks for length of each field to be 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would add a key, i.e.

```
[ 'items' => [
       ['line1' => 'foo', 'postcode' => 'bar'],
       ['line1' => 'baz', 'postcode' => 'qux']
    ]
]
```

And then use `'items' => 'required|min:1'`.

If this isn't possible, could you add an `after()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) to your Request (I haven't done this so not sure if it works):

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if (count($validator->getData())<1) {
            $validator->errors()->add('input', 'There must be at least one input');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `withValidator` option worked for me. Thank you!